# Search not redirecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search

I am trying to follow [Simple Search Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form?view=comments). As trivial as it seems I cannot get it to work. I basically have the following set up:

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag products_path, method: :get do %>
            <p>
              <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
              <%= submit_tag "Search", title: nil %>
            </p>
        <% end %>
```

**prodcut_controlle.rb**

```
    def index
    @products = Product.search(params[:search])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @products }
    end
  end


  def show
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @cart = current_cart #Get current cart

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @product }
    end
  end
```

**Product.rb***

```
  def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ['title LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
    else
      find(:all)
    end
  end
```

What I am effectively aiming for is that when the user searches a particular `product` they are redirected to the product. In this case it would be the `products show` which is why I have put the `@products = Product.search(params[:search])`. How do I go about achieving something so basic -.-

Answer (score 0):

Unless your routes are highly unusual, in your form tag `products_path` refers to the `index` action not the `show` action.

Your code that does the search should go into `index` instead, and then perform the redirect to `show` if you can determine a single product to "show".

As for redirecting, assuming that you have a single search result (or are choosing one for the user), you can redirect to that `show` page with:

```
product = @products.first // Somehow you're choosing one of your @products here

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to product }
  //...
end
```

Now, what you'll need to deal with are two more cases:
1. What if there are no products? 
2. What if there is more than one product?

Both can be handled with your index action as a general search results page.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    if @products.blank? || @products.size > 1
      render :action => "index"
    else
      redirect_to @products.first
    end
  end
  // ...
end
```

In a real system I would put the whole "do I have a single product" question into its own function, but hopefully this gets you moving in the right direction.

== Docs

[Redirecting](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html)

[render](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render)

Comment: I have performed the necessary changes and I was aware of this....However in my application, I have prevented non-registered and non-admin users from seeing the products page. So therefore what I need to do is make it so that instead of being redirected to the `index` page then the `show` I want the controller to directly go to the `show` page if that makes sense

Comment: Your form is asking the browser to call the index action directly. There is no redirect involved. Once inside your index action, then you can redirect to show or whatever else you want.

Comment: right okay, so providing that I have updated my index method to include `@products = Product.search(params[:search])` how would I then get it to redirect to the show?

Comment: Updated answer to address your recent questions about the mechanics of redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be perform searching on index action rather than show action. So move `@products = Product.search(params[:search])` line to index action. Also note that your form path `products_path` is submitting the request at index action. Hope this helps